# JS using onclick event on li to display block

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, onclick

HTML:

```
<script>function dropdown()
{        console.getElementById("").style.display="block";
}</script>
<div id="dropdown">
    <ul>
        <li onclick="dropdown()"><a>Menu</a>
             <ul id="Menuitems">
                 <li><a href="">item 1</a> </li>
                 <li><a href="">item 2</a> </li>
                 <li><a href="">item 3</a> </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Css:

```
#dropdown ul{
 display: block; 
}
#dropdown ul li {
     display: block;
     background-color: #558c89;
     color: #ffffff; 
}
#dropdown ul li ul {
     display: none; 
}
#dropdown ul li:hover > ul { /*this is what the onclick event should do*/
     display: block; 
}
```

The onclick should start the function "dropdown()" which needs to: "display: block;" on #dropdown ul li

Comment: This makes no sense at all.

Comment: @techouse http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253086/code-block-adjustment

Comment: where is your html? create a jsfiddle and what is your question?

Comment: What's `console.getElementById("")`?

Comment: do you have a restriction on using JQuery ?

Comment: @techouse It was plainly obvious that OP neglected the blank line before the code block, resulting in a seemingly nonsensical question.

Comment: @Xeltor I'd love to see you use jQuery to do this more simply than the code in my answer.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Ah, that... Well, no I was looking beyond that, at the JS code. That was the "nonsense".

Comment: @techouse why doesn't this make sense? i don't understand why this is a stupid question. please explain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the list ID and you're calling the selector on the console (when you want to be selecting on the document).

```
<script>
function dropdown()
{        
    document.getElementById("Menuitems").style.display="block";
}
</script>
<div id="dropdown">
    <ul>
        <li onclick="dropdown()"><a>Menu</a>
             <ul id="Menuitems">
                 <li><a href="">item 1</a> </li>
                 <li><a href="">item 2</a> </li>
                 <li><a href="">item 3</a> </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tmaB9/

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
<li onClick="dropDown(this);">
```

This is important, so your function knows *which* element you clicked on. Then...

```
function dropDown(li) {
    var submenu = li.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];
    if( submenu) {
        submenu.style.display = submenu.style.display == "block" ? "" : "block";
    }
}
```

This will toggle the visibility of the submenu :)

Answer (score 0):

here is a quick example of what i think you want (provided you can use JQuery):

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#dropdown ul li').on('click', function dropdown() {
            //console.getElementById("").style.display = "block";
        });
    });

<div id="dropdown" class="dropdown">
    <ul>
        <li>menu 1</li>
        <li>menu 2</li>
        <li>menu 3</li>
        <li>menu 4</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```