# Menu dropdown in html, css and js from mobile and desktop

Tags: javascript, html, css

i refer to this thread: [JS using onclick event on li to display block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23761478/js-using-onclick-event-on-li-to-display-block)

From desktop is ok but how do i do the same thing but that from the mobile you can touch the "disappearing" menu and make sure that it remains visible until the next touch?

I'm currently using this code here:

```js
function dropdown() {
  document.getElementById("Menuitems").style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
#dropdown ul {
  display: block;
  transition-duration: 1s;
}

#dropdown ul li {
  display: block;
  background-color: #212121;
  color: #ffffff;
}

#dropdown ul li ul {
  display: none;
}

#dropdown ul li:hover>ul {
  /*this is what the onclick event should do*/
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="dropdown">
  <ul>
    <li onclick="dropdown()"><a>Menu</a>
      <ul id="Menuitems">
        <li><a href="">item 1</a> </li>
        <li><a href="">item 2</a> </li>
        <li><a href="">item 3</a> </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Please take a moment to take the [tour] and read [ask]. You need to provide at least an illustration of what you mean by "disappearing" menu. The code in that question immediately shows or hides the clicked menu's submenu, unless you add some CSS or otherwise alter the code in some way. Please [edit] your question to include the code you are using.

Comment: Thanks and sorry for my mistake. I insert the code, css and js script.

Comment: the mobile phone works like this, to open the menu you have to touch the navigation bar, the phone doesn't have a mouse you can't use the hover

Comment: Yes of course but the problem still remain, how can i solve?

Answer (score 0):

I just added an active class onclick .. the active class toggles on every click. and just add the same hover effect to active class

```js
function dropdown() {
  document.getElementById("Menuitems").classList.toggle("active");
}
```

```css
#dropdown ul {
  display: block;
  transition-duration: 1s;
}

#dropdown ul li {
  display: block;
  background-color: #212121;
  color: #ffffff;
}

#dropdown ul li ul {
  display: none;
}

#dropdown ul li:hover>ul,
#dropdown ul li>ul.active{
  /*this is what the onclick event should do*/
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="dropdown">
  <ul>
    <li onclick="dropdown()"><a>Menu</a>
      <ul id="Menuitems">
        <li><a href="">item 1</a> </li>
        <li><a href="">item 2</a> </li>
        <li><a href="">item 3</a> </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```